# Should I use MinMaxScaler which was fit on train dataset to transform test dataset, or use a separate MinMaxScaler to fit and transform test dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, normalization, predict, data-processing

Assume that I have 3 dataset in a ML problem.

`train dataset`: used to estimate ML model parameters (training)

`test dataset`: used to evaulate trained model, calculate accuracy of trained model

`prediction dataset`: used only for prediction after model deployment

I don't have `evaluation dataset`, and I use **Grid Search** with k-fold cross validation to find the best model.

Also, I have two python scripts as follows:

`train.py`: used to train and test ML model, load train and test dataset, save the trained model, best model is found by Grid Search.

`predict.py`: used to load pre-trained model & load prediction dataset, predict model output and calculate accuracy.

Before starting training process in `train.py`, I use **MinMaxScaler** as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

scaler.fit(x_train)   # fit only on train dataset
x_train_norm = scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test_norm = scaler.transform(x_test)
```

In `predict.py`, after loding prediction dataset, I need to use the same data pre-processing as below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

scaler.fit(x_predict)   
x_predict_norm = scaler.transform(x_predict)
```

As you can see above, both fit and transform are done on prediction dataset. However, in `train.py`, fit is done on train dataset, and the same MinMaxScaler is applied to transform test dataset.

My understanding is that test dataset is a simulation of real data that model is supposed to predict after deployment. Therefore, data pre-processing of test and prediction dataset should be the same.

I think separate MinMaxScaler should be used in `train.py` for train and test dataset as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler_train = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_test = MinMaxScaler()

scaler_train.fit(x_train)   # fit only on train dataset
x_train_norm = scaler_train.transform(x_train)

scaler_test.fit(x_test)   # fit only on test dataset
x_test_norm = scaler_test.transform(x_test)
```

What is the difference?

Value of `x_test_norm` will be different if I use separate MinMaxScaler as explained above. In this case, value of `x_test_norm` is in the range of [-1, 1]. However, If I transform test dataset by a MinMaxScaler which was fit by train dataset, value of `x_test_norm` can be outside the range of [-1, 1].

Please let me know your idea about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `.transform()` MinMax scaling does something like: `(value - min) / (Max - min)` The value of `min` and `Max` are defined when you run `.fit()`. So the answer - yes, you should fit MinMaxScaller on the training dataset and then use it on the test dataset.

Just imagine the situation when in the training dataset you have some feature with Max=100 and min=10, while in the test dataset Max=10 and min=1. If you will train separate MinMaxScaller for test subset, yes, it will scale the feature in the range [-1, 1], but in comparison to the training dataset, the called values should be lower.

Also, regarding Grid Search with k-fold cross-validation, you should use the [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline). In this case, Grid Search will automatically fit MinMaxScaller on the `k-1` folds. Here is a good example of how to organize [pipeline with Mixed Types](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html).

Comment: Thanks. 
Regarding Grid Search, if Grid Search automatically fits MinMaxScaler, does it mean that I don't need to use MinMaxScaler in "train.py"?
What about "predict.py"?

Comment: Not certainly in that way. The idea to put all transformation steps in one pipeline. In this case, `pipeline.fit(X, y)` will automatically train scalers, encoders, and the model. After you can just pickle the pipeline (that is in training.py). In the predicti.py you do `pickle.load` and the full pre-trained pipeline is available to do prediction. Check the last link in the answer.

Comment: What about running`.fit()` on train_set and test_set, that is use MinMaxScaler before splitting the whole dataset into train_set and test_set. Will that lead to a better test prediction but maybe a worse product prediction?